# dynwg: A DynDNS watchdog for WireGuard via systemd-networkd

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking

## Preface

I'm using [WireGuard](https://www.wireguard.com/) as a VPN solution to connect a remote client permanently to my home server. 
Unfortunately due to Consumer DSL-related IP address changes, the client loses the connection to the server.
Because of its philosophy of simplicity, re-resolution of the server's (DynDNS) hostname is out of scope for WireGuard itself.
The official package `wireguard-tools` contains amongst other stuff, a script [`reresolve-dns.sh`](https://github.com/WireGuard/WireGuard/blob/master/contrib/examples/reresolve-dns/reresolve-dns.sh) which I modeled [my Python solution](https://github.com/conqp/dynwg) upon.

## Purpose

The script below is the main part of a watchdog, that iterates over `*.netdev` and `*.network` systemd-networkd configuration file pairs that are WireGuard interface configurations.
The script performs two tests:

1. Did the remote server IP change?
2. Is the remote server not reachable over the WireGuard interface?

If at least one is true, it will attempt to recover the WireGuard connection using `wg`.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
"""WireGuard over systemd-networkd DynDNS watchdog daemon."""

from configparser import ConfigParser
from contextlib import suppress
from json import dump, load
from pathlib import Path
from socket import gaierror, gethostbyname
from subprocess import DEVNULL, CalledProcessError, check_call
from sys import stderr


CACHE = Path('/var/cache/dynwg.json')
SYSTEMD_NETWORK = Path('/etc/systemd/network')
NETDEVS = SYSTEMD_NETWORK.glob('*.netdev')
PING = '/usr/bin/ping'
WG = '/usr/bin/wg'


def error(*msg):
    """Prints an error message."""

    print(*msg, file=stderr, flush=True)


def is_wg_client(netdev):
    """Checks whether the netdev is a WireGuard client interface."""

    try:
        _ = netdev['WireGuardPeer']['Endpoint']     # Check if endpoint is set.
        return netdev['NetDev']['Kind'] == 'wireguard'
    except KeyError:
        return False


def configurations():
    """Yields the available configurations."""

    for path in NETDEVS:
        netdev = ConfigParser(strict=False)
        netdev.read(path)

        if is_wg_client(netdev):
            name = path.stem
            path = path.parent.joinpath(f'{name}.network')
            network = ConfigParser(strict=False)
            network.read(path)
            yield (name, netdev, network)


def ip_changed(host, cache):
    """Determines whether the IP address
    of the specified host has changed.
    """

    try:
        current_ip = gethostbyname(host)
    except gaierror:
        error(f'Cannot resolve host: "{host}".')
        cache.delete(host)
        return False

    cached_ip = cache.get(host)
    cache[host] = current_ip

    if cached_ip is None:
        return False

    print(f'Host "{host}":', cached_ip, '→', current_ip, flush=True)
    return cached_ip != current_ip


def gateway_unreachable(network):
    """Pings the respective gateway to check if it is unreachable."""

    try:
        gateway = network['Route']['Gateway']
    except KeyError:
        error('No gateway specified, cannot ping. Assuming not reachable.')
        return True

    command = (PING, '-c', '3', '-W', '3', gateway)

    try:
        check_call(command, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)
    except CalledProcessError:
        print(f'Gateway "{gateway}" is not reachable.', flush=True)
        return True

    return False


def reset(netdev, current_ip):
    """Resets the respective interface."""

    try:
        interface = netdev['NetDev']['Name']
    except KeyError:
        error('NetDev→Name not specified. Cannot reset interface.')
        return False

    try:
        pubkey = netdev['WireGuardPeer']['PublicKey']
    except KeyError:
        error('WireGuardPeer→PublicKey not specified. Cannot reset interface.')
        return False

    command = (WG, 'set', interface, 'peer', pubkey, 'endpoint', current_ip)

    try:
        check_call(command)
    except CalledProcessError:
        error('Resetting of interface failed.')
        return False

    return True


def check(netdev, network, cache):
    """Checks the respective *.netdev config."""

    try:
        endpoint = netdev['WireGuardPeer']['Endpoint']
    except KeyError:
        error('WireGuardPeer→Endpoint not specified. Cannot check host.')
        return False

    host, *_ = endpoint.split(':')  # Discard port.

    if ip_changed(host, cache) or gateway_unreachable(network):
        try:
            current_ip = cache[host]
        except KeyError:
            error('Current IP unknown. Cannot reset interface.')
            return False

        return reset(netdev, current_ip)

    return True


def main():
    """Daemon's main loop."""

    with Cache(CACHE) as cache:
        for name, netdev, network in configurations():
            print(f'Checking: {name}.', flush=True)
            check(netdev, network, cache)


class Cache(dict):
    """Host name → IP address cache."""

    def __new__(cls, _):
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, path):
        super().__init__()
        self.path = path
        self._dirty = False

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.dirty = self.get(key) != value
        return super().__setitem__(key, value)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.load()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *_):
        self.dump()

    @property
    def dirty(self):
        """Determines whether the cache is considered dirty."""
        return self._dirty

    @dirty.setter
    def dirty(self, dirty):
        """Sets whether the cache is dirty."""
        self._dirty = self._dirty or dirty

    def delete(self, key):
        """Deletes the respective key."""
        with suppress(KeyError):
            del self[key]
            self.dirty = True

    def load(self):
        """Loads the cache."""
        try:
            with self.path.open('r') as file:
                self.update(load(file))
        except FileNotFoundError:
            self.dirty = True   # Ensure initial file creation.

    def dump(self, force=False):
        """Dumps the cache."""
        if self.dirty or force:
            with self.path.open('w') as file:
                dump(self, file, indent=2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any suggestions for improvement are welcome.